# Issue with bubble graph labels in ADF DVT component

Tags: java, graph, oracle-adf

I am working on a bubble graph issue where the graph is distorted whenever the Y-axis labels are long 
Ideally the graph should appear like the Normal.gif.

[image: Normal screen image]
But if the labels are long, it is appearing like distorted.gif.

[image]
Hence , I tried to show only the first 15 characters of the labels followed by 3 ellipses (3 dots ...). But still there is so much space between the label names and the plot area. [image: (AfterChange.gif)]
Is there any way to reduce this space. Any idea which property of the graph controls this space. Also whenever the labels are concatenated to show only the first 15 characters, we need to show the full name when we hover the mouse over the name. How do we achieve this? Please let me know if you have any pointers on this.

```
  <dvt:x1MajorTick lineWidth="0" tickStyle="GS_NONE"/>
  <dvt:x1Title text="#{HcmGoalTopGenBundle['MenuItem.Performance.AddtoPerformanceGoal']}"
               rendered="true">
    <dvt:graphFont bold="true"/>
  </dvt:x1Title>
  <dvt:y1Axis majorTickStepAutomatic="false"
              majorTickStep="#{bindings.YMinorTick.inputValue}"
              axisMinAutoScaled="false" axisMaxAutoScaled="false"
              axisMinValue="#{bindings.YLowerBoundary.inputValue}"
              axisMaxValue="#{bindings.YUpperBoundary.inputValue}"></dvt:y1Axis>
  <dvt:y1TickLabel>
    <af:convertNumber pattern="#{applCorePrefs.numberFormatPattern}"/>
  </dvt:y1TickLabel>
  <dvt:y1MajorTick lineWidth="0" tickStyle="GS_NONE"/>
  <dvt:y1Title text="#{hcmperformancedocspublicuiBundle1['OText.Potential.PotentialRating']}"
               rendered="true">
    <dvt:graphFont bold="true"/>
  </dvt:y1Title>
  <dvt:seriesSet defaultMarkerShape="MS_HUMAN"/>

  <dvt:shapeAttributesSet>
    <dvt:shapeAttributes component="GRAPH_DATAMARKER"/>
  </dvt:shapeAttributesSet>
  <dvt:legendArea position="LAP_RIGHT" rendered="false"/>
</dvt:graph>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I worked on this too..and found out that this is a framework issue. the same has been reported to the framework team